# How to concatenate integers variables as a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have these lines of code:

```
Num1 = random.randint(1, 10)

Num2 = random.randint(1, 10)

Num3 = random.randint(1, 10)

Num4 = random.randint(1, 10)

Number = Num1 + Num2 + Num3 + Num4

print(Number)
```

I want to make it so that instead of it adding the Nums together and printing a number between 4 and 40, it prints it like this: "1234".

Answer (score 3):

You need to convert each value to a string and concatenate them. One simple way is

```
number = "%d%d%d%d" % (Num1, Num2, Num3, Num4)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can print the variables and define a separator character like so:

```
print(Num1, Num2, Num3, Num4, sep="")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print ''.join([str(x) for x in [1,2,3,4]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is using [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).

```
number = "{}{}{}{}".format(Num1, Num2,Num3, Num4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can encapsulate the statement with str():

```
Num1 = str(random.randint(1, 10))

Num2 = str(random.randint(1, 10))

Num3 = str(random.randint(1, 10))

Num4 = str(random.randint(1, 10))

Number = Num1 + Num2 + Num3 + Num4

print(Number)
```